# Python querying a dataframe with pipe separated columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

A dataframe contains columns which are pipe separated and others which aren't. In order to find the most popular genre I've used code below to count num of unique values. However, how can one deal with the pipe to return the true most popular genre?

df.genres.value_counts()

Results:

```
Drama                                    712
Comedy                                   712
Documentary                              312
Drama|Romance                            289
Comedy|Drama                             280
                                        ... 
TV Movie|Animation|Fantasy                 1
Science Fiction|Action|Comedy|Horror       1
Drama|Comedy|Thriller|Romance|Foreign      1
Horror|Animation|Mystery                   1
Romance|Comedy|Drama|Music                 1
Name: genres, Length: 2039, dtype: int64
```

```
df.head()
    id  runtime genres
0   135397  124 Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller
1   76341   120 Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller
2   262500  119 Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller
3   140607  136 Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Fantasy
4   168259  137 Action|Crime|Thriller
```

```
df.dtypes
id          int64
runtime     int64
genres     object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join all the rows of the `genres` column using the pipe character, then re-split them based on pipes. In this way, you get a list of the all genres, whether or not they were originally pipe-separated.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'genres': ['Drama', 'Comedy', 'Documentary', 'Drama|Romance', 'Comedy|Romance', 'Documentary|Romance']})

popular_list = '|'.join(df['genres']).split('|')

print(popular_list)
```

Output:

```py
['Drama', 'Comedy', 'Documentary', 'Drama', 'Romance', 'Comedy', 'Romance', 'Documentary', 'Romance']
```

Then, it's just a matter of finding the highest frequency item and the corresponding number of counts if required:

```py
true_most_popular = max(set(popular_list), key = popular_list.count)

print(true_most_popular)

print(popular_list.count(true_most_popular))
```

Output:

```py
Romance
3
```

Comment: @ BenedictanjwThe following code produces -- df.genres.nunique() -- produces 2039 unique combinations for genre with the pipe operator. Is there a way of  writing the first line of your code above without having to type out each combination.

Comment: You don't have to type it out - you already have it in your genres columns. I had to just to get some data to work with. Maybe I'm understanding this wrongly. Could you print the output of df.head()?

Comment: @ Benedictanjw Note genres is not a string - how to deal with this when using your code? I receive the following error with the popular list = line of code > TypeError: sequence item 424: expected str instance, float found.

Comment: Can you try running that line as popular_list = '|'.join(df.head()['genres']).split('|') ? If this works, then it's because you probably have NaNs somewhere further down in your column (position 424). You can get rid of this by: df = df.loc[~pd.isnull(df['genres']), :]